# The retarded green's function in the extended nambu basis

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, greens-functions

Lets say we have a non-interacting translation invariant Hamiltonian $H$ in a matrix form:

$$H=\Psi^{\dagger}\bar{H}\Psi$$

where $\Psi^{\dagger}=(\Psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}\quad \Psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger} \quad\Psi_{\downarrow}\quad-\Psi_{\uparrow})$ is the extended nambu spinor.

In such a basis what is the meaning of a particular element of the matrix representation of the retarded green function:

$$\bar{G}^{R}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\omega-\bar{H}+i\delta}$$

what is $\bar{G}^{R}_{ij}$?

Comment: Since that $i G^{Ret}(xt,x't') = \langle GS \vert \text{T} \psi_m(xt) \psi^\dagger_{m'}(x't') \vert GS \rangle$ so $G^{Ret}_{ij}(\omega)$ is the propagator in the $\omega$ space.

Comment: What do you mean what is $\tilde{G}^R_{ij}$? You ask about the physical meaning? Or do you want a mathematical equation in terms of specific operators?

Comment: @gingras.ol Well, a mathematical equation would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general recipe, the retarded Green's function is defined as
$$
G^{R}_{ij}(t,t') = -i \theta(t,t') \langle \{\psi_{i}, \psi_{j}^{\dagger} \} \rangle,
$$
where $\theta$ is the step-function, and $\{ ,\}$ denotes anticommutator. $\psi_{k}$ based on your suggested language is k-th elemnt of $\Psi$. For instance, $\psi_{1}= \Psi_{\uparrow}$.
The full retarded Green's function would be
$$
G^{R}(t,t')= -i \theta(t,t')
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle  \{ \Psi_{\uparrow}(t) , \Psi^{\dagger}_{\uparrow}(t') \} \rangle&
 \langle \{ \Psi_{\uparrow}(t), \Psi^{\dagger}_{\downarrow}(t') \} \rangle&
 \langle \{ \Psi_{\uparrow}(t), \Psi_{\downarrow}(t') \} \rangle
& -\langle \{ \Psi_{\uparrow}(t), \Psi_{\uparrow}(t') \} \rangle\\
\langle \{ \Psi_{\downarrow}(t) , \Psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}(t') \} \rangle
 & \langle \{ \Psi_{\downarrow}(t) , \Psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger}(t') \}\rangle
& \langle \{ \Psi_{\downarrow}(t) , \Psi_{\downarrow}(t') \} \rangle
& -\langle \{ \Psi_{\downarrow}(t) ,\Psi_{\uparrow}(t') \} \rangle \\
\langle \{ \Psi^{\dagger}_{\downarrow}(t) , \Psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}(t') \} \rangle & 
\langle \{ \Psi^{\dagger}_{\downarrow}(t) , \Psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger}(t') \} \rangle&
 \langle \{ \Psi^{\dagger}_{\downarrow}(t) , \Psi_{\downarrow}(t') \}\rangle
 & -\langle \{ \Psi^{\dagger}_{\downarrow}(t) ,\Psi_{\uparrow}(t') \} \rangle\\
-\langle \{ \Psi^{\dagger}_{\uparrow}(t) , \Psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}(t') \}  \rangle& 
-\langle \{ \Psi^{\dagger}_{\uparrow}(t) , \Psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger}(t') \} \rangle& 
-\langle \{ \Psi^{\dagger}_{\uparrow}(t) , \Psi_{\downarrow}(t') \} \rangle& 
\langle \{ \Psi^{\dagger}_{\uparrow}(t) ,\Psi_{\uparrow}(t') \} \rangle
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The suggested generic definition of the retarded Green's function in your question is just the Fourier transform of the above matrix in the basis where $\overline{H}$is defined.

Comment: Thanks. I don't fully understand the relation between Green the "function" and Green the "operator".
Could you give me a source so that I can get this cleared up?

Comment: Please remember that the Green's function is a particular two-point "function" of "operators". Most likely a review on real-time Green's functions can be illustrative.

Comment: Could you please suggest something specific? I have read the usual treatments in Doniac and Walecka, but neither of them seems to treat operator-wise aspects of the Green's function.

Comment: Reading "Nonequilibrium Many-Body Theory of quantum systems" by Stefanucci and van Leeuwen is most likely helpful. You can also try to learn the "Keldysh Green's function" formalism.